# CoreData fetch() returns objects unordered

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swift4

I have an entity that has a name and for testing purposes I named them in order of most recently added(0) to oldest added object.

When I first launch the app it loads my entities in order(0,1,2...) but if I change the name attribute of any entity the order is all messed up. I use the numberOfRows tableview function to test this as is is called when the tableView is reloaded(correct me if I am wrong):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return 0}
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "GraphDataSet")
    do {
        graphSetArray.removeAll()
        graphSetArray = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    for i in 0..<graphSetArray.count{
        let set = graphSetArray[(graphSetArray.count-1)-i]
        print("Name: ", set.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String)
    }
    return graphSetArray.count
}
```

As far as I understand this empties the Array holding all the entities(although I believe this is pointless as its being set in the next line but I wanted to make sure), then fetches the entities filling the array. I then loop through the array backwards(recent to old) and get the entity of that index and print its name attribute.

This is the console output every time I start the app:

```
Name:  Optional("0")
Name:  Optional("1")
Name:  Optional("2")
Name:  Optional("3")
Name:  Optional("4")
Name:  Optional("5")
Name:  Optional("6")
```

Here is after I change an entities name value to the same value it was(just for the sake of keeping it in order but technically changing the value and reloading the tableView):

```
Name:  Optional("5")
Name:  Optional("4")
Name:  Optional("1")
Name:  Optional("3")
Name:  Optional("0")
Name:  Optional("2")
Name:  Optional("6")
```

Not sure why this happens because I am fetching the data the same way every time, and every time I restart the app the order is back to normal. My only theory is that when an entities attribute is changed that the ordering is messed up with no pattern. So I am wondering whether this theory is correct, and if it is then is there any way to stop the ordering from changing?

EDIT: One thing I just noticed is that after it goes out of order, every time after that when I change the value it maintains this unsorted order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order is not necessarily kept within CoreData, but you can add a sort descriptor to your fetch request in order to get it ordered in a certain way. If you want it to be sorted by the time added, you will need to add a timestamp to your model and sort by that.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "GraphDataSet")
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
...
```

Comment: ok, but is there any reasoning for it loading once in order then everytime after that it loads the same unsorted order. Every time restarting the app the unsorted order is different but consistent within that execution of the app

Comment: It is probably kept in ram and therefore doesn't change the order afterwards, but I can't tell you for sure. What I can tell you is that the order is not guaranteed to stay the same.

Comment: ok I'm implementing a time stamp, I just use an attribute for that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you are using an Array as the backing store? The automatically generated versions can actually be Sets rather than Arrays.

Your fetch request can also have sort descriptors applied to it, to ensure that the results - regardless of how they are stored - are shown to you in the way that you specify.

Comment: I didn't see any way to specify that it is fetched as an array, but I beleive it is as a set would not be able to be indexed using subscripting as I am in the posted code.  I read a solution where someone suggested saving an index as an attribute of the entity then use the sort order, is that the proper way of doing it? Also with that method what would be the best solution for deleting entities?

Comment: My apologies, for some reason I was thinking of your GraphDataSet as having been fetched from a relationship.
It sounds like you should actually be using sort descriptors - as well as not fetching the data like that every single time within the table view delegate method.

Ideally you should look into the CoreData books by Ray Wenderlich or objc.io

Comment: I am going to implement sort descriptors. Is there another way of fetching other than every time within the delegate? if a value gets added/deleted wont it need to check the whole array?

Comment: Thanks for the help though, I will look into the book

Comment: If you're working with UITableViews you should look to use NSFetchedResultsController. Wired up correctly, you won't have to worry about updating the table view as it will all get refreshed for you after you change your data.

Comment: That definitely sounds like it would be useful to my situation, I will do some research on it.

Comment: Glad I could help 